# Can a hyperlink close the previous window in Google Sites?

Tags: links, google-classic-sites

I want to use hyper-linked images for navigation between Google Sites pages.
Right now the hyperlink creates a new tab when opened.

Is there a way for the hyperlink to 'replace' the current page - rather than open a new tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have it open in the same page by unchecking the box labeled "Open this link in a new window:

https://sites.google.com/site/siteshelphowtos/google-sites-instructions/images/imagesaslinks